# Maven:I am mavenizing oracle service bus application using jdeveloper 12c

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jdeveloper, osb, maven-scm

I have checked out code from SVN using SCM into my empty jdeveloper workspace. How Can I point in current pom which checked out code from SVN central repo to build my latest code from SVN. Can anyone help me?

Right now I am using Command line to change the work-space and building. Any solution that can be done in pom?

Comment: how are you currently building, what have you been trying? would be good to know.

Comment: I am building through maven using oracle service bus plugin.

Comment: In JDeveloper you just need to righ-click the Service Bus Project and choose "Run Maven"->"package". This will build an sbar archive for the code you checked out. If you need to build another version from SVN, you need to checkout that version and do the same. You have the same pom.xml for all code versions.

Comment: My manager wants me to do using mvn command line but not with IDE options. I have written a bat file to change the workspace and build that application.